# ArcGIS Enterprise: Layer Registered as versioned issues

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, feature-service, arcgis-enterprise

I want to publish a feature service from an Enterprise file geodatabase to Portal yet when I try to validate the layer in ArcGISPro I get error 00231. I checked the feature dataset in which the layer is contained and it is versioned. What am I missing here? What else can I check?

[image: Versioning Enabled]

[image: Validation Error]

Comment: File geodatabase does not support versioning.

Answer (score 1):

Your feature dataset may be registered as versioned, but your connection to the database needs to be registered with the hosting ArcGIS Server site.  You can click the ellipses to the right of the error message, and choose Register data source.  This will open a dialogue box to register the database connection string with the hosting server, allowing the ArcGIS Server to establish the connection to the underlying enterprise geodatabase when using the feature service.